# php - store user selection temporarily

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a page where users make a selection on a page, when selection is made the user gets transfered to a page upload.php where selections are processed and uploaded to a db.

[image]

When the user is **not logged in** he can still make a selection on Make_selections.php page but when directed to upload_selections.php the script gets stopped and a javascript modabox gets displayed asking for user to login before selections are recorded

[image]

```
//USER IS NOT LOGGED DISPLAY LOGIN MODAL  
if (!isset($_SESSION['name']) && !isset($_SESSION['FBID'])) {
?>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox(

            '<form id="register_form" method="post" action="myLoginScript.php"><label for="login_name">Email:</label><br /><input type="text" id="login_name" name="email" size="30" /><br /><label for="login_pass">Password: </label><br /><input type="password" id="login_pass" name="password" size="30" /><br /><input type="submit" name="login" value="login" /></p></form>',
    );
});

    </script>
    </div>
    <?
```

**My Problem**

When user logs in to modal-box the user gets logged in but his **selections from Make_Selections.php are lost.**

What are my best options here to get user to login but **still keep the selections** he made so that the user does not have to complete the selection process over again

Comment: session can store all the variables you want

Comment: Use SESSIONS for keeping data from the previous page. Or you can use serialize data and keep it in the hidden field. Whe the user is logged in you can deserialize this data and use it the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like the following in Upload_selection.php:

```
//USER IS NOT LOGGED DISPLAY LOGIN MODAL  
if (!isset($_SESSION['name']) && !isset($_SESSION['FBID'])) {
    $_SESSION['selections'] = $_POST; // <-------NEW LINE
?>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox(

            '<form id="register_form" method="post" action="myLoginScript.php"><label for="login_name">Email:</label><br /><input type="text" id="login_name" name="email" size="30" /><br /><label for="login_pass">Password: </label><br /><input type="password" id="login_pass" name="password" size="30" /><br /><input type="submit" name="login" value="login" /></p></form>',
    );
});

    </script>
    </div>
```

After the user is logged in you can simply call the selections from the session:

```
$_SESSION['selections']['YOUR INPUT NAME HERE']
```